# mvvm light messenger check if a class is already registered?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

In MVVM Light, can we check if a class is already registered? i.e. if I call the following method twice, it is registering twice. I need it only once.

Messenger.Default.Register(this, message => DisplayError(message));

which is a good place to register an instance to Messenger? Constructor or Loaded event handler?

which is a good place to unregister?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, there is no API to check if an instance or a class is registered in the Messenger. You need to track this down yourself.

I usually register in the constructor, and expose a Cleanup method where I unregister before the object is removed.

Comment: Sorry I just saw you tagged with Windows Phone 7, so you obviously do a navigation app ;) So yeah OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatingFrom can be used as triggers for the ViewModel (the page's DataContext) and other objects to register/unregister to the Messenger. This is not a rule though, the real answer is "it depends".

Comment: Actually, I needed one for showing errors in a dialog box. So the communication is from VM to view. So, in general if I register in OnNavigatedTo and unregister in OnNavigatedFrom (in code-behind, not in VM), do you think I will be safe? i.e. it will not be fired twice, right?

Comment: @Jonna if that wasn't a safe way to do it it would cause some fundamental problems in other areas. You should be fine with this.

Answer (score 0):

In case you switched to Microsoft's CommunityToolkit.Mvvm in the meantime, you can use

```
if (!WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.IsRegistered<MyMessage>(this))
{
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(this, (r, m) => Foo());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to note that this exists now in MVVMLight. You can use

```
if(SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<YourType>())
{
    // Don't register again!
}
```

Comment: That's for the IoC container though, not the Messenger.